# List of Lists item selection not working properly?

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm

in reference to my earlier question  [Binding List of Lists in XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188025/binding-list-of-lists-in-xaml) i am facing a small issue.
[image]

The above window has a ListView control where its each ListViewItem itself is another ListView. So the parent ListView consists of 8 (ListView)items, where each child item ListView consists of 1,1,1,2,1,2,1,2 items respectively. The below image has been taken when i am trying to click on the poster of 'Bug's Life'. However the selection is not updating the bottom two TextBlock controls which are bound to the ViewModel *Movie* property. It is still showing the 3 Idiots movie which was selected before. However if i click on the *27 Dresses* poster it will update the *Movie* property. Please help me in identifying and solving this issue.

Comment: Please show some XAML / code that illustrates how the problem bindings have been done.

Comment: Show binding of selected item and ViewModel's Movie property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ViewModel`, you need to reset the `SelectedItem` for all the `ListView`s (by setting it to `null`) before assigning the new value like so:

```
private Movie m_SelectedMovie;

public Movie SelectedMovie
{
  get
  {
    return m_SelectedMovie;
  }
  set
  {
    if (m_SelectedMovie != value)
    {
      m_SelectedMovie = null;
      OnPropertyChanged("SelectedMovie"); // -> So the ListViews unselect everything
      m_SelectedMovie = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("SelectedMovie");
    }
  }
}
```