# WinRT XAML data binding a List of objects that contain a List

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have a `List` of objects that contain another `List`. I want to bind both `List`s to different controls (one nested within the other - a `ListView` as `GridViewItem`). But I can't get the [xaml](/questions/tagged/xaml) to work.

Very close to this question comes [Binding List of Lists in XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188025/binding-list-of-lists-in-xaml).
And there is an article regarding this in the MSDN documentation:
[How to bind to hierarchical data and create a master/details view](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh758322.aspx) - could be the solution, but I find it difficult to apply it to my code.
Other articles touch this topic, but not that good and also as a new user I'm not allowed to include more than two hyperlinks in a question.

My code looks similar to this (changed to city / restaurant scenario for clarity):

**Model:**

```cs
public class City
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    List<Restaurant> RestaurantList { get; set; }
    //.. also a constructor with parameters for the properties and an overriding toString method that returns Name
}
public class Restaurant
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    List<Uri> UriList { get; set; }
    //.. also a constructor with parameters for the properties and an overriding toString method that returns Name
}
```

**Code-behind (LoadState method):**

```cs
    //.. getting a List of cities (with restaurants), that is being created in some model class
    this.DefaultViewModel["Items"] = Cities;
```

Some people set the `DataContext` instead. I got this from the MSDN tutorials and it worked so far. But I'm not sure which is "better".

**Okay now the XAML:**

I want to have a `GridView` with the Cities as `GridViewItem`s. Within one `GridViewItem` there's a `Grid`, displaying the `City`'s `Name` in the top row and a `ListView` below. The `ListView` contains the `Restaurant`s (only of that `City`!). The `ListViewItem`s are only `TextBlocks` showing the `Restaurant`'s `Name`.
I want only the `Restaurant`s to be clickable.

Like this:
[image: http://imageshack.us/a/img687/5576/listviewasgridviewitem.png]

```xml
<!-- the following line is at the very top and the reason why it should work without setting DataContext explicitly -->
DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
<!-- ... -->
<GridView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionMode="None">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="500" Width="200" Margin="50" Background="Gray">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="5*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                <ListView
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding RestaurantList}" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Tapped="Restaurant_Click"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

This way only gray boxes are shown. When changing the `TextBlock`'s binding to `Text="{Binding}"` then at least the `Name`s of the Cities are shown. Which I don't understand and also don't want, because I guess the overriding of the `toString` methods is not meant to be used this way. The `Name`s of the `Restaurant`s don't show up in both cases.

Also, the scrolling somehow broke in this view, but that's a different story I suppose.

**So: What's wrong with the data binding in the XAML?**

Comment: Welcome on SO! The databinding needs public properties: e.g. `public string Name { get; set; }` and `public List<Restaurant> RestaurantList { get; set; }`. Is it a "typo" in your sample or the source of your problem?

Comment: Oh dear! That's actually it! Thanks a lot! When you make it an answer I will mark it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The databinding engine needs [public properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743643.aspx) (the link is about WPF but the same concepts apply in WinRT):

> You can bind to public properties, sub-properties, as well as
>   indexers, of any common language runtime (CLR) object.

But if you don't specify it explicit the compiler treats members by default ["the most restricted access you could declare for that member"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521459/what-are-the-default-access-modifiers-in-c) e.g. `private` in your case.

So you need to declare your properties as `public`:

```
public class City
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Restaurant> RestaurantList { get; set; }
}

public class Restaurant
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Uri> UriList { get; set; }
}
```