# Binding List<List<string>> to DataGridView in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, binding

Is there any way to bind a list of lists to a DataGridView so that the first list is a group of columns and then each list it contains will be treated as the rows?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188025/binding-list-of-lists-in-xaml) for XAML which seems like something vaguely similar, but can't find any way for normal winforms.

Comment: bind it to what ? a control ? a GridView ?

Comment: Probably easier to convert your list-lists to a DataTable and bind to that.

Comment: Yes, I thought that converting to a `DataTable` would be the easiest option - but that direct access might be a tidier way of approaching it?

Comment: Binding to a DataGridView. Sorry mentioned it in the title, forgot to state it again in the question.